Bulk SMS Send Complete Guide Node.js
I need to create a grade management system where teachers add marks, and admins verify and send results to parents via SMS. I'm using the MERN stack with Node.js. Any free or paid SMS options that can handle 500+ students within 2 hours? Thank
I want a complete and detailed solution of it.

The BulkSMS.com API can handle that message volume. You pay per message - it’s not free.
I’m not sure what you mean by “complete and detailed solution”, but the API documentation is on the site.
